# What character is this kid with brown hair, a green and turquoise striped T-shirt and purple pants?

Tags: dc, comics, character-identification

Brown hair, striped t-shirt (green and turquoise), purple pants, black and gray shoes.   Looks like a kid.

[image: The character figure/toy]

Comment: How do you know it is from DC comics?  That looks like a speaker in his abdomen and a button for a pocket.  Does it say something?

Comment: apart from the fact that this toy turned out to be from a scifi franchise, what is scifi&fantasy about this question to make it on topic?

Comment: @user13267 nothing in the question is on-topic, but per [What to do when a vague identification question is off-topic, but the answer is on-topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10533/98028), the answer being on-topic means the question should stay open.

Comment: @Jenayah Is there any better resource that actually puts that policy in Scifi SE?  That is a user saying that you should vote to reopen and say it's on topic, but is there any actual consensus that it _is_ on topic?  It seems like there should be a more direct meta question for that.

Comment: @JMac not sure what you mean? I agree that this isn't the most upvoted question on SFF Meta but it's what being done so far, so kind of a "policy by habit" thing

Comment: @Jenayah It just seems like quite a backwards policy.  The questions get closed if they offer no elements that suggest it belongs to scifi/fantasy.  Answers shouldn't really be what determines the topicality of a question IMO.  That seems pretty standard across SE sites.  That's why it seems strange to me that it acts as a de-facto policy here without any clear meta-guidance.

Comment: @Jenayah There actually is a better, more definitive meta discussion on it https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12170/is-a-story-identification-question-on-topic-if-it-doesnt-include-genre-defining (Kinda funny that Valorum seems to have changed opinions on that over the course of the year between these two questions)

Comment: @JMac the difference between the two is that in the earlier one, the issue was when the Q had an _on-topic answer_, whereas the most recent one is about Qs that may or may not have answers yet. I see your point though, you might want to ask it on Meta (we had the same a while ago with [consensus on tagging story-id with the solved work](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12283/98028)). We're getting off-topic though so if we are to continue this discussion, may I suggest you come around to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe) :)

Comment: @Jenayah I think that the two meta questions together cover all the scenarios pretty well.

Answer (score 36):

I think it is [Kevin](https://www.attireskirt.com/2004-krypto-the-superdog-kevin-w-jet-pack-works-talking-action-figure-mattel), Krypto's new owner in *Krypto the Superdog*. (Unlike the comics, he is adopted by a normal Earth boy.)

[image: Cover for *Krypto the SUperdog* showing Kevin and Krypto]

Specifically, it looks like this may be the figure from the [Krypto & Kevin's First Adventure](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000809NZA) set.

[image: Krypto & Kevin's First Adventure]

Comment: There's some nice pics here as well; https://www.attireskirt.com/2004-krypto-the-superdog-kevin-w-jet-pack-works-talking-action-figure-mattel

Comment: His shirt pocket is a different color from the toy though

Comment: @Izkata It's very obviously the same toy, though. Probably just a minor manufacturing defect/difference.